# Prestashop. Forbidden al intentar descargar un archivo

Tags: archivo, prestashop, descarga

Estoy desarrollando un módulo para subir ficheros a la carpeta downloads de Prestashop y hasta ahi todo bien.

El problema es a la hora de intentar descargar alguno de estos ficheros, que me da el siguiente error:

```
Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document.
```

Este es el enlace que estoy usando:

```
<a href="/download/{$csv['name_file']}_{$csv['name_csv']}" class="btn btn-default">Descargar</a>
```

Espero que alguien pueda iluminarme!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado una alternativa funcional. He modificado el enlace por un pequeño formulario:

```
<form action="{$link->getModuleLink('jmarketplace', 'sellercsvlist', ['csv_name' => $csv['name_file']], true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post" class="std">
      <input type="submit" id="download_csv" name="download_csv" value="{l s='Download' mod='jmarketplace'}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
</form>
```

Y en el controlador dentro del postProcess() el action correspondiente:

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('download_csv')) {
        $csv = Tools::getValue('csv_name');

        $csv = SellerCSV::getCSVByName($csv);
        $csv_name = $csv['name_file'] . '_' . $csv['name_csv'];

        $file = _PS_DOWNLOAD_DIR_ . $csv_name;
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
```

Con esto se descarga correctamente el archivo deseado. Espero que esto sirva para alguien más!